# to find average of differences between time values stored in a file

Tags: python, shell

I have a file having time and ***re-usable*** session numbers. I am trying to find average of difference of times of these sessions. I'll explain what i did but my logic breaks in specific scenario.

### File looks like :-

```
<Date and time> session:1234 start
<Date and time> session:2345 start
<Date and time> session:3456 start
<Date and time> session:1234 stop
<Date and time> session:7890 start
<Date and time> session:4567 start
<Date and time> session:2345 stop
<Date and time> session:4567 stop
....
```

What I did : - I did sort as per session number, then find difference of subsequent lines and later average of all those differences. But I got wrong value because this file also contains few "session:xx start" lines which do not have "stop" and few "session:xx stop" lines which do not have "start".

So, my question is how can i remove such lines. My logic breaks because i blindly         arrange lines as per session number and later find time difference between subsequent lines.

If there is another way of doing this, let me know. I'm happy to try.
Thank you !!

Comment: How did you sort the lines? did you load the lines in some data structure?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that, for any session number, if I have two consecutive starts, I can always delete the first one, if they are sorted by datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to proceed creating a dictionary for every `session_id` like this:

```
sessions = { 1234 : { start: DateTime, stop: DateTime} ... }
```

In order to do this, it would be enough to iterate over each line of your file and add to your `sessions` dictionary the session id as a key (`sessions[session_id]`). For every session you can easily add the `start` and the `stop` key.

Later, you can process this `sessions` dictionary and remove all the `session_id` that do not contain both `start` and `stop`. With your final list you can calculate the difference and then make an average of all your results.

Comment: what if a session has multiple start and stop times? the OP explicitly states that sessions are ***re-usable***

Comment: In that case the `start` and `stop` will get overwritten. Another option could be that when a `session_id` has both a `start` and a `stop`, the dictionary is moved to another dictionary (e.g. `session_completed`) with another id. In this way you do not have to care about re-usable `session_id`

Comment: I see. anyway I think the OP is not looking for a strategy, but for some working code ;)

Comment: @mabe02 Thanks for hint. Let me try to implement that way. Moving dictionary to another dictionary is something new that I'll try today.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a solution based on the assumption that *if I have two consecutive starts, I can always delete the first one, if they are sorted by datetime*

I slightly changed the imput file replacing `date ad time` with a number. The code could be easily adapted to manage date and time.

The code is structured in three blocks:

1. read and parse the file into a useful data structure
2. sort the data for each session
3. remove unwanted elements

here's my approach:

```
import re
import collections

with open(your_file_name_here, 'r') as f:
    # parse each line in a dict like
    # {sessionid: [(time, start/stop), ...]}
    pattern = re.compile('(\d+) session:(\d+) (\w+)')
    lines = f.readlines()
    sessions = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for line in lines:
        m = re.match(pattern, line).groups()
        sessions[m[1]].append((m[0],m[2]))

    # for each session, sort the list
    # I kept this loop separate from the next one
    # since OP said he had data already sorted
    for k,v in sessions.items():
        sessions[k] = sorted(v, key=lambda x: x[0])

    # for each session remove unwanted elements
    for k, v in sessions.items():
        # group elements two by two
        # added a default element to manage the last element of the list
        for el in zip(v,v[1:]+[('','start')]):
            if el[0][1] == 'start' and el[1][1] == 'start':
                v.remove(el[0])
```

example file content:

```
1 session:1234 start
2 session:2345 start
3 session:3456 start
4 session:1234 stop
5 session:7890 start
6 session:4567 start
7 session:2345 stop
8 session:4567 stop
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

- a dictionary for active sessions containing the start date, and the session id as key
- a dictionary containing a list of the durations per session, having the session id as key

I would then process the input file *sorted by time*:

- when a start line is found, put the start time in the active sessions dictionnary. If one was already there, it would be a non terminated session (stop line lost) and should be ignored
- when a stop line is found, search for the corresponding start time in active sessions dictionary. If none is found, just ignore that stop line without start. Else, compute the session duration and add it to the list for that session and remore the element from the active sessions dictionnary.

I would use defaultdict(list) for the durations to simply add a duration without having to wonder whether the list for that session already exists.